# problem with obtain the phase between two signals

Tags: fourier-analysis

I want to obtain the correct sign of the phase difference between two interpolate function,

[image]

For do that, I use the following code:

```
Data1 = Table[Signal1[t], {t, 480000, 490000, step}];  
Data2 = Table[Signal2[t], {t, 480000, 490000, step}]; 
ffts1B = Fourier[Data1, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}];    
ffts2B = Fourier[Data2, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}];  

 maxB1 = Max[Abs[ffts1B]];    
 posB1 = First[First[Position[Abs[ffts1B], maxB1]]];
 maxB2 = Max[Abs[ffts2B]];  
 posB2 =  First[First[Position[Abs[ffts2B], maxB2]]];
  \[CapitalDelta]\[Phi]12F =   Arg[ffts1B[[posB1]]] - Arg[ffts2B[[posB1]]]
```

The problem is that when I set step equal to 0.1, 0.01 or 0.001 the sign of the phase difference changes. Or when I change the time interval, Is there no method to determine the correct sign of the phase difference?. I tried to put a small interval, but does not work.

thanks

Comment: What is the form of `Singal1[t]` and `Signal2[t]`?  They look like sine waves but we need the frequency, amplitude and phase you are using. Further where does the interpolation come in?

Comment: is a solution of a big differential equation system.

Comment: Can you give us a minimum working example. Will a sine wave do for the signals?

Comment: You could use `FindMaximum`. Or `NMinimize` combined with `NIntegrate[Abs[Signal2[t]-Signal1[t + a]], {t, 480000, 4810000}]]`

Comment: what would be the function of FindMaximum?

Comment: `FindMaximum[Signal1[t], {t, 480000}]` and `FindMaximum[Signal2[t], {t, 480000}]`. Then just take the difference between the $t$s.

Comment: thanks I will try that

Comment: I would guess that `Max` is picking up the positive or negative frequency component more-or-less randomly as you change the step. You could restrict the search to the first half of `ffts1B` and `ffts2B`.

Comment: @anderstood Using the maximum peaks in the time domain is likely to give misleading answers, if significant noise is present. Try cross-correlation to find the (signed) time delay which gives biggest cross-power, and multiply by the frequency. This has the effect of averaging the noise over the whole dataset. With this coarse approach, the time delay is quantized to the sample interval. If you need greater precision you can interpolate some extra points and repeat the exercise, searching around the coarse maximum.

Comment: @JamesCunnane I agree, _if significant noise is present_ (which does not seem to be the case here).